# Why have a trait bound in rust that is the same as trait being impl

Tags: rust

I came across some code I don't fully understand where the trait being impl is the same as the where clause. For example the `futures::future::Map` struct includes the debug implementation

```rs
impl<Fut, F> Debug for Map<Fut, F>
where
    Map<Fut, F>: Debug,
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), Error>
```

This seems to me to indicate that Debug should be implemented for Map struct when debug is already implemented. This is confusing as it seems as if this implementation would never be called yet it obviously works correctly. Apologies for the beginner question but I haven't been able to find anything in the book and I don't really know what to google here. Am I missing a key something about how trait implementations and bounds work?

Comment: The `Map` in `where` is an internal private type, see https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.25/src/futures_util/future/future/mod.rs.html#48-53.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the source code (which is not made is since all these implementations are [macro-generated](https://github.com/rust-lang/futures-rs/blob/cd1f29ac1c783841612a4c4054f2431644c846b6/futures-util/src/lib.rs)), it seems to me that the second `Map` corresponds to an internal type, namely [`map::Map`](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.25/src/futures_util/future/future/mod.rs.html#51). It's a bit unfortunate how the doc is rendered.